# Is this roughed in basement sewer pipe in the right location?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, basement, rough-in

My basement is unfinished but the sewer drains were roughed-in and I have some blueprints of possible layouts when I bought the house (from the previous homeowner not the builder). The roughed-in drain for the toilet and the sink drain appear to be too far into the room based on the plans that I have. The toilet drain pipe is 3 feet in from the wall and the sink drain is about 20 inches in from the wall.

Is this plumbed so that there would be a 20-24 inch think wall behind the toilet?
I realize that there should be some space from the wall for framing/insulation, but this seems a little excessive to me.

Behind this wall is all soil beneath the ground floor garage.

[image: Basement Down]
[image: Basement Straight]

Contractor Blueprint location
[image: Contractor Blueprints]

Measured locations
[image: Measured Distances]

Comment: It looks like the installer had a different layout in mind than the blueprint drawing you provided. I also suspect the 2" pipe is the vent for the toilet and if so, I don't see a stub out for a lav.